# Should I prune fungus-infected vegetable plants or destroy them?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, blight, eggplant

I have some eggplant and tomato plants. My eggplants appear to have some kind of fungus. It's being raining quite a bit in Central, FL; as a result, I think they are infecting the tomato plant too. Should I remove the eggplants leaves, prune them, or destroy them?

*click on pictures for full size*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These little spots are a normal protective measure for lots of plants.  It is fungus that the plant itself is getting rid of by allowing the part of the leaf that has been 'infected' by fungus spores to die and then the dead part drops out causing a black spot or hole.  Very common this time of year for both your eggplant as well as tomatoes, squash...everything in your garden.

Prune off any yellowed leaves, especially those near the ground.  It'll help with aeration (air being able to blow through the plants and keeping leaves dry and less affected by fungal spores).  Your plants could use some fertilizer, however.  Make sure you use fertilizer with less Nitrogen than the Phosphorus and Potassium numbers!!  That bark is depleting the available nitrogen as well because decomposers need nitrogen to decompose stuff that is not decomposed.

Otherwise you've got viable, healthy plants!